# JS Assigning a New Object to a previously used variable (TypeError: mangoFruit.showName is not a function)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running through a basic tutorial on JavaScript Objects. And I am creating an Object using the function constructor:

```
function Fruit () {};
```

Then I am defining a function on that Objects Prorotype:

```
Fruit.prototype.showName = function () {
    console.log("This is a " + this.fruitName);
}
```

I am then instantiating that object and calling the function on that object.

```
 var mangoFruit = new Fruit();
 mangoFruit.showName();
```

And using Node I get the following error:

```
TypeError: mangoFruit.showName is not a function
```

I'm using SublimeText3 with a package that allows me to execute my JavaScript file directly in the console. It does this by making a call to Node.

Edit: I get the same error when running node from my terminal.

**My Code:**

```
function Fruit (theColor, theSweetness, theFruitName, theNativeToLand) {

this.color = theColor;
this.sweetness = theSweetness;
this.fruitName = theFruitName;
this.nativeToLand = theNativeToLand;

this.showName = function () {
    console.log("This is a " + this.fruitName);
}

this.nativeTo = function () {
    this.nativeToLand.forEach(function(eachCountry) {
        console.log("Grown in: " + eachCountry);
    });
  }
}

var mangoFruit = new Fruit("Yellow", 8, "Mango", ["South America", "Central America", "West Africa"]);
mangoFruit.showName(); // This is a Mango.
mangoFruit.nativeTo();

function Fruit () {};

Fruit.prototype.color = "Yellow";
Fruit.prototype.sweetness = 7;
Fruit.prototype.fruitName = "Generic Fruit";
Fruit.prototype.nativeToLand = "USA";

Fruit.prototype.showName = function () {
    console.log("This is a " + this.fruitName);
}

Fruit.prototype.nativeTo = function () {
    console.log("Grown in: " + this.nativeToLand);
}

var mangoFruit = new Fruit();
mangoFruit.showName();
mangoFruit.nativeTo();
```

**Node JS Error**

```
/Users/michael/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/CodingInterviewPrep/JavaScriptTutorials/ProtoTypes.js:20
mangoFruit.showName(); // This is a Mango.
           ^

TypeError: mangoFruit.showName is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/michael/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/CodingInterviewPrep/JavaScriptTutorials/ProtoTypes.js:20:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

**Node Version**

```
node -v
v6.8.1
```

Comment: Works perfectly in my Node 4.3.1

Comment: @Michael Teifel What node version do you use?

Comment: I'm running Node 6.8.1

Comment: What if you run the code directly in node?

Comment: Same error from my terminal

Comment: I realized I have other lines in the code where I use the mangoFruit variable. Wouldn't me creating a new object and assigning it to that variable overwrite the old object?

Comment: Why is this down voted so much?? It seems a genuine issue, right?

Comment: @andymccullough: I guess it was downvoted because the code in the original version of the question worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called **Hoisting**

Your code as you have written it (simplified for clarity):

```
function Fruit() {

};

var fruit = new Fruit();
fruit.showName();

function Fruit() {
    console.log('second definition of Fruit');
};

Fruit.prototype.showName = function () {
    console.log("This is a " + this.fruitName);
}
```

Now as node.js sees it and processes it:

```
var fruit;
function Fruit() {

};

function Fruit() {
    console.log('second definition of Fruit');
};

fruit = new Fruit();
fruit.showName();

Fruit.prototype.showName = function () {
    console.log("This is a " + this.fruitName);
}
```

As You can see You have overwritten Fruit function (the second definition has moved above `new Fruit()` call) while `Fruit.prototype.showName` did not. So when you called `showName` it was not defined yet.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. It makes it very clear.